# PyQt5: How to print a QUrl without the module name

Tags: python, text, pyqt5, qurl

I am trying to grab a url from the web, but no matter what I do, it also prints the entire module for the QUrl:

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtCore import QUrl
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication
from PyQt5.QtWebEngineWidgets import QWebEngineView

app = QApplication(sys.argv)
url = 'http://stackoverflow.com'
wv = QWebEngineView()

wv.load(QUrl(url))
print str(QUrl(url))
wv.show()
app.exec_()
```

which gives me :

```
PyQt5.QtCore.QUrl(u'http://stackoverflow.com')
```

I am only interested grabbing the unicode string, without the module name:

```
u'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

I know I can just print the url, but this is just for reproducing the problem in a bigger app.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [QUrl](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html) class has a dedicated [toString](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#toString) method for this:

```
>>> u = QtCore.QUrl(u'http://stackoverflow.com')
>>> u.toString()
u'http://stackoverflow.com'
```

You can also pass in an argument with [Formatting Options](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qurl.html#UrlFormattingOption-enum), which will modify how the url is displayed (e.g. by removing the query or stripping trailing slashes).

Comment: thank you it worked.

    u = QUrl(QUrl((url)))
    print u.toString()